# how to apply the backgroud process in my iPad application without effecting the process running on foreground?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, multitasking, background-process

I'm Developing an iPad application where I need to download file from the Webservice and I don't want it affect any other process running on the foreground.

I am displaying the data from the local database in my app and also this data is coming from  the web service.

Help Is Appreciated.

Thank You Very Much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few thoughts:

1. you can run the download process on separate thread.
2. Write a class as below

> @interface FileDownloader : NSOperation
>
> //with following methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:
                         [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                          [NSURL URLWithString:fileRecord.fileURLString]] delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

NSURLConnection and its delegate method will allow an asynchronous(background thread) load of a URL request.

Refer the [NSURLConnection Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

After getting the data from the server you should parse it on another secondary thread. Then you can save it to the Database.

You can find a better demonstration in the Apple sample apps. Please check the [TopPaid app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TopPaid/Introduction/Intro.html) .

This sample app don't have a Database management module. But will teach you to develop a Universal (iPad and iPhone compatible app).

Answer (score 1):

you can use thread use below method to detach thread

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(yourMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

now perform your task in method

```
-(void) yourMethod {
//ur work

}
```

good luck

Comment: thank you  i did use  this method  to call the  downloading class  (connection methods)

Answer (score 0):

When downloading from a service in the background, I prefer to use synchronous calls running on a separate thread.  This is how I do it in most of my apps.

call my generic method that spins a new thread

```
[[MyServiceSingleton sharedInstance] doSomeWorkInBackground:param1];
```

within singleton - define private method - doSomeWorkBackgroundJob (I use the empty category approach) to call within doSomeWorkInBackground method

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomeWorkBackgroundJob:) withObject:param1];
```

within background job - create pool, do work, drain pool

```
- (void)doSomeWorkBackgroundJob:(NSString *)param1 {
NSAutoreleasePool *pool;
pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
assert(pool != nil);

// you can call another method here or just create your synchronous request and handle the response data

[pool drain];
```

}